# The contextMenu is not applied to the child view but to the parent view when long pressing the child view

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu

## What I want

I'm making a component. This component is used to display a list of tags. I want a context menu to pop up on the tag when the user long-presses it. Like this:

[image]

## What I got

[image]

You see, the context menu display on the tag's container instead of the tag.

## My code

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct AddVision: View {
    @State private var visionTitle: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Basic Information")) {
                        TextField("Input Vision Title Please", text: $visionTitle)
                    }
                    Section(header: Text("Tags")) {
                        TagsView(screenWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            addNewVision()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addNewVision() {
        print("add new vision")
    }
}

struct TagsView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    // 标签行数组，每一个元素表示一行标签
    @State private var groupedItems: [[Tag]] = [[Tag]]()
    
    // 新标签标题
    @State private var newTagTitle = ""
    
    // 显示标签添加输入框
    @State private var showNewTagInputField = false
    
    // 显示菜单
    @State private var showContextMenu = false
    
    // 显示警告
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    // 聚焦
    @FocusState private var keyboardFocused: Bool
    
    // 屏幕宽度
    let screenWidth: CGFloat
    
    init(screenWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.screenWidth = screenWidth
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(groupedItems, id: \.self) { itms in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(itms, id: \.self) { tag in
                        Text(tag.title ?? "")
                            .font(.callout)
                            .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color(hue: 0.364, saturation: 0.939, brightness: 0.628)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .padding()
                            .frame(height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .background(Color(hue: 0.387, saturation: 0.969, brightness: 0.965, opacity: 0.207))
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                            .cornerRadius(100)
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button {
                                    deleteTheTag(tag)
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                }

                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                if showNewTagInputField {
                    TextField("my tag", text: $newTagTitle, onCommit: addTag)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/Color(hue: 0.364, saturation: 0.939, brightness: 0.628)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .background(Color(hue: 0.387, saturation: 0.969, brightness: 0.965, opacity: 0.207))
                        .frame(alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(100)
                        .focused($keyboardFocused)
                        .onAppear {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                                keyboardFocused = true
                            }
                        }
                }
                
                Button {
                    showNewTagInputField = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.035, brightness: 0.053, opacity: 0.243))
                .frame(height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/24.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .frame(alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(100)
            }
            .animation(.easeOut, value: showNewTagInputField)
        }
        .onAppear {
            buildTagGroupList()
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteTheTag(_ tag: Tag) {
        // 删除标签
        viewContext.delete(tag)
        
        // 刷新标签列表
        buildTagGroupList()
    }
    
    private func buildTagGroupList() {
        // 待处理的标签
        var tags = [Tag]()
        
        // 查询标签
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Tag>(entityName: "Tag")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        do {
            let results = try viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for result in results {
                tags.append(result)
            }
        } catch {
            print("查询标签的时候出现错误")
        }
        
        var groupedItems: [[Tag]] = [[Tag]]()
        
        // 一行tag已经占据的宽度
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        
        // 临时存储一行的元素
        var tempItems = [Tag]()
        
        // 循环取出的标签
        for word in tags {
            // 新建一个Label组件
            let label = UILabel()
            
            // 设置Label的内容
            label.text = word.title
            
            // 设置label根据里面text的长度改变其宽度
            label.sizeToFit()
            
            // label的宽度，一个label两边都16点的padding，所以一个label的宽度需要加上32
            let labelWidth = label.frame.size.width + 32
            
            if (width + labelWidth + 32) < screenWidth {
                width += labelWidth
                tempItems.append(word)
            } else {
                width = labelWidth
                groupedItems.append(tempItems)
                tempItems.removeAll()
                tempItems.append(word)
            }
        }
        
        groupedItems.append(tempItems)
        
        self.groupedItems = groupedItems
    }
    
    private func addTag() {
        // 检查是否输入内容
        if self.newTagTitle.isEmpty {
            // 关闭新标签添加输入框
            showNewTagInputField = false
            return
        }
        
        // 向数据库中添加一个标签
        let tag = Tag(context: viewContext)
        tag.id = UUID()
        tag.title = self.newTagTitle
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("保存新标签的时候出现错误")
        }
        
        // 重新获取数据
        buildTagGroupList()
        
        // 清空新标签输入框
        self.newTagTitle.removeAll()
        
        // 关闭新标签添加输入框
        showNewTagInputField = false
    }
}

struct AddVision_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddVision()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

I tried several methods, but all failed.

How should I modify my code?

Thanks

I google this problem with key word like this:

> SwiftUI contextMenu is not applied to the child view but to the parent view

Unfortunately, I didn't find what I needed.

I also tried Youbube with key word but I got less T_T

I asked GPT several times and it does gave me some solusion, and I tried all of them

ALL FAILED T_T

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine for me (Xcode 15 beta 5). If the problem persists you should edit your question and add all the code which is necessary to compile ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let tags2DList = [["123", "456", "789"], ["987", "654", "321"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(tags2DList, id: \.self) { tagList in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(tagList, id: \.self) { tag in
                        Text(tag)
                            .font(.callout)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hue: 0.364, saturation: 0.939, brightness: 0.628))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(height: 24.0)
                            .background(Color(hue: 0.387, saturation: 0.969, brightness: 0.965, opacity: 0.207))
                            .frame(alignment: .center)
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button {
                                    // some action
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                }
                            }
                            .cornerRadius(100) // <- Changed order for better animation
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for replying so late. I was also very confused when I saw your video, I really can't get your results in my code. I posted the complete code, please help me to check what is wrong. Thanks again.